# TypeScript function type with fixed parameters but inferred return type

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out how to create a type that is a function whose parameters are set but whose return value is generic and should be inferred from the provided function.

This particular use case is that I'm defining a set of selectors on data. All of the selectors have the same state input, and their output will be a property of that state:

```
type ApplicationState = { count: number };
const selectCount = (state: ApplicationState) => state.count;
```

I could simply do this via setting `ApplicationState` as the type for each parameter, but I am trying to give the selectors themselves a type:

```
const selectCount: ApplicationSelector = ({ count }) => count;
```

I have tried this:

```
type ApplicationSelector = (state: ApplicationState) => infer R ? R : any;
```

However, the [documentation on this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) makes it clear that this `infer` syntax is supposed to be used with `extends`, but in this case, I'm not sure what to extend.

Is there a way for me to declare a function type with a set parameter argument and infer its return type?

Comment: Not possible. Inference for variables is either all or nothing, you either let the compiler infer or you specify it yourself. We can do more interesting things with function inference, but in this case since your goal is to have explicit types for the variable there is nothing we can do you would have to write it out explicitly in your variable type annotation as `ApplicationSelector<number>` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat trick you can use. Create a wrapper function that does nothing but restrict and forward the types.

```js
type AppState = {count: number};

function appSelector<S extends (state: AppState) => any>(selector: S) {
    return selector;
}

const selectCount = appSelector(({count}) => count);
```

Here's the resulting type:

> `const selectCount: ({ count }: AppState) => number`

And you do in fact retain autocomplete and type checking for destructured properties like `({count})` there.